# Connection between AMFPHP2.1 to Flex

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, amfphp, away3d

my friend built an AS3 game in IMAC, and he sent game file to me while i'm using win7 system. after complete configuration, it came a problem:"NetConnection.Call.BadVersion" in console of Flex. It works fine when open .php in localhost/amfphp, and the URL in actionscript is correct, and info to connect to mysql is also correct.

can anyone help me? please?

I did google search, the only solution is to change some statements in gateway.php, but that's for 1.9 version, mine is 2.1

Comment: The BadVersion error usually happens if the server is returning something that Flex can't interpret as AMF. Have you tried using a http-sniffer, e.g. Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or Service Capture (http://kevinlangdon.com/serviceCapture/) to see what really get's returned from the server? Also, is all of this now running on your localhost or are you experiencing the problems on a production server?

Comment: You should not change anything in gateway.php

Answer (score 1):

It may be a crossdomain problem. You just try the following xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```